# Should I repeat whatever the imam speaks in salah?

Tags: salat, imam-al-jamaah

Should I stay quiet or repeat whatever the imam speaks while praying salah in congregation?

Answer (score 3):

If the Imam is reciting Surah al-Fatiha out-loud, then there is a difference of opinion between scholars:

- Majority of scholars including *Ahmed Bin Hanbal, Malik ibn Anas* and some *Hanafi* and *Shafi* Scholars say you should **not repeat** the Fatiha

Their evidences:

**From Hadith:**

> Narrated AbuHurayrah:
>   The Prophet (ﷺ) said: The imam is appointed only to be followed. This version adds: When he recites (the Qur'an), keep silent."
>   Abu Dawud said: The addition of the words "When he recites, keep silent" in this version are not guarded. The misunderstanding, according to us, is on the part of Abu Khalid (a narrator). [[Abu Dauwd]](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/2/214)

**From the Quran:**

> So when the Qur'an is recited, then listen to it and pay attention that you may receive mercy. http://quran.com/7/204

- Rest of scholars (*As-Shafi*, *Bukhary* and others) say you **must repeat** the fatiha after the imam. Their evidence:

**From Hadith:**

> 'Ubadah b. al-Samit reported the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) as saying :
>   the prayer is not valid I one does not recite fatihat al-kitab and something more, sufyan( the narrator) said: This applies to a man who prays alone. [[Abu Dauwd]](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/2/432)

***As for repeating after him while reciting other surahs. then you don't have to***

Comment: Also there's this Hadith for reading behind imam :

Comment: The stronger opinion is that you read the Fatiha while he is reading it. Another option to read it after the taemeen.

Comment: Well i disagree with your answer as it's more or less the opposite imam abu Hanifa doesn't recite  behind the imam while Malik say's one could read for oneself and Imam Shafi'i and ibn Hanbal are reading after the ta'min see my asnwer here http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23449/rules-for-reading-4-fard-with-jamat-or-alone/26154#26154

Comment: I think that even the majority of scholars who say its not mandatory do not say it should not’ be done as youve said, so most likely it can still be done, the fatihah, recited.

Answer (score -1):

In congregational salat, when Imam recites the Surah al-Hamd and other surah in the first and second Rak'at of the Fajr,Maghrib and Isha prayers, you should listen and if you do not hear the voice of the Imam, it is Mustahab that you should recite Surah al-Hamd and Surah silently.

**Reference:**

http://www.hawzah.net/fa/question/questionview/64167

Comment: No references please substantiate